# Workaround for "Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)" in CC Mode

Tags: search, byte-compilation, cc-mode, monkey-patching

Emacs 24.x and 25.x have a bug in CC Mode which can result in some operations failing with the error

> Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)

For example, I can reproduce it with the following file `a.c`:

```c
#if defined(FOO) || \
    defined(BAR)
```

and running

```sh
emacs -Q -nw a.c --eval '(occur "FOO")'
```

(Running `M-x occur RET FOO RET` after that works. I have a bigger file where this doesn't work.)

This is a known bug: [#28850](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=28850). The fix is in two commits [46540a1c7adb1b89b6c2f6c9150fe8680c3a5fba](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=46540a1c7adb1b89b6c2f6c9150fe8680c3a5fba) and [ad68bbd0da4ed90117f09dc2344c0c3d9d728851](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=ad68bbd0da4ed90117f09dc2344c0c3d9d728851) which were first released in Emacs 26.1. I can confirm that Emacs 26.3 works with both the minimal example above and my real file.

The machines I use most often run Emacs 24.5.1 or Emacs 25.2.2, so I need a workaround for Emacs 24.x and 25.x. My init file has several hot fixes for Emacs bug and I'm fine with adding one more. I normally hot-fix in an `eval-after-load` form, either by advising a function or by replacing its definition.

But here there's a bug in the function `c-make-font-lock-search-form` which, if I understand correctly, is used **at compile time**. This is the relevant part of `cc-fonts.el`:

```el
(eval-and-compile
  …
  (defun c-make-font-lock-search-form (regexp highlights)
    ;; this code needs to be patched
    …)
  (defun c-make-font-lock-context-search-function (normal &rest state-stanzas)
    (c-make-font-lock-search-form …)) ;; this call needs to be patched
)

(c-lang-defconst c-cpp-matchers
  t `( … ,(c-make-font-lock-context-search-function …)))
```

So `cc-fonts.elc` contains buggy byte-compiled code. Merely fixing the buggy function after `cc-fonts.elc` is loaded won't help. Even fixing the function before `cc-fonts.elc` wouldn't help.

**How can I work around this bug? The workaround needs to work on Emacs 24.x and 25.x.** The workaround needs to fix the "Invalid search bound" error, without disabling fontification. I don't mind if there's a slight loss of performance or accuracy compared to the official fix.

Comment: Scanning the bug report, does it help to turn off `jit-lock-stealth`?

Comment: @Drew Isn't it off by default? `jit-lock-stealth-time` defaults to nil, it's nil in my configuration, and its documentation states “If nil, stealth fontification is never performed.”. I don't do anything special regarding `jit-lock-mode`, so it's turned on with default parameters. I think Jit Lock is just the way the reporter happened to trigger the bug. With me the trigger was `occur`.

Comment: Dunno. The bug report seemed to be about the problem happening when it's non-`nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big-hammer approach is to add `cc-mode` to your config, as it is maintained externally and tends to be very backwards-compatible.

The latest version [says](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/compat.php) "CC Mode 5.34 should work out of the box with Emacs >= 24.5 ... It may well work on earlier versions."

The [5.33](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/changes-533.php) release notes say "The minimum versions supported ... Emacs 23.2".

Comment: n.b. `M-x c-version` says Emacs 26.3 comes with CC Mode version 5.33.2